# Best way to port mobile app

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

I am android developer.

I need to create different apps(single app but run on different devices) running on a single code base and make them run on iPhone, meego phones & windows phones.

How can i start? Which is the best IDE to use to port to different platforms?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is a famous framework for crossplateform applications